# Export a content provider’s CONTRACT CLASS to another android project?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

For self training purpose, I created a content provider in an android project/application (App1). This content provider has a contract class named MyContentProviderContract.class. 
In another application (App2), I want to use ContentResovler to access App1’s MyContentProvider using MyContentProviderContract.

My question is, what is the STANDARD/BEST  way to export (it may not be the right word of course) MyContentProviderContract.class  from App1 to App2.

Thanks in advance for your answers.
Gilles

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to put the Contract class in a shared library (jar or android library) and include this library in both App1 and App2.  This way as the contract class changes you only need to make those changes in one place (the shared library) and they'll be reflected everywhere.

Comment: I just tested your solution successfully. Thanks for you answer. However, is it the only solution you have in mind? I am trying to figure out which way is used when one imports standard ContactsContract or other android system's content provider. If possible I'd like to keep my Contract Class in my content provider project and allow the client to take only the Contract class and not the implemenenation, that is not the whole project.

Comment: Contract classes for system ContentProviders are stored as part of the Android API so they don't run into this problem.  If you're developing an android app, your using the api, and will automatically have access to the contract class.  The shared lib approach is the best I've found .  It allows third-party developers to more easily access your content provider while all you provide them is the library (not source).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification about contracts classes for system content providers. It makes perfect sense for me now.

Comment: The other solution I see to share a content provider with third-party developers is to ask them to include the source of my contract class in a package of their project, Without pushing the comparison too far it would be a little bit like when C++ developers provide a .h file of their library so that third-party developers can include them in a .cpp files.

Comment: That's certainly another option.